# SSL Proxying with mutual authentication

Tags: ssl, proxy, authentication, https

I have a bunch of backend servers each them should make https-requests. I want all my https traffic inspected and controled by few number of machines (many times fewer than server farm) - that's why I want make all servers work through a forwarding proxy to establish all ssl (and then proxy my https-requests).

I found [squid sslbump feature](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslBump), but it works only for server authentication. I need not only server auth, but mutual auth too. Do you know something that does the same trick as sslbump but also includes mutual auth?

PS All client certificates are under my control and I make access from my proxy server to them.

Comment: Interesting. I was considering mutual authentication as a mechanism to defeat connections where there is an SSL Proxy to disrupt my trust chain.

Comment: Hi pls. I am trying the samething to enable ssl mutual authentication with SQUID and have figured out its possible in SQUID version 4 which is yet to come. Did you get this working in SQUID 3.x versions? if yes, then which feature is required to be used ?